# destructuring assignment of array stored in object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

say I have an object:

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 'a', baz: [1,2,3] }
```

how to assign the value of `baz` to get the head and the tail of the array?

I mean so that the effect is the same as that of the code below, except for I do not want to use the extra variable `baz`:

```
{ baz } = obj;
[head, ...tail] = baz;
```

I know I can say `[head, ...tail] = obj.baz` but my question is about the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for instance do

```
let {baz: [head, ...tail]} = obj;
```

by combining the patterns together.